# How to find the proper URI of a file which is present on HDFS

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to get creation date of a file which is present in HDFS using Scala-Spark. 
In my research, I've found out we can do it using the below code:

```
val conf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
val dirPath = new Path("path of the file")
val filestatus = fs.listStatus(dirPath)
filestatus.foreach(f => println(f.getModificationTime))
```

The above code will list the files in descending order of their creation date. But when I try run the code, I get the error at this line:

```
val dirPath=new Path("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/input")
dirPath: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path = hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/input
val fileStatus = fs.listStatus(dirPath)
```

**Error Message:**

```
**`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/input, expected: file:///`**
```

I gave "quickstart.cloudera" in the path as I see this property in the core-site.xml file:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020</value>
  </property>
```

I gave "localhost" in place of "quickstart.cloudera" and tried to run it. But I still face the error. Could anyone tell me what is the mistake I am doing here and how can I correct it.

I also tried to refer the file directly by doing:

```
val dirPath=new Path("/user/cloudera/input"‌​)
```

I got that path from below command:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/cloudera
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera          5 2017-11-27 23:13 /user/cloudera/input
```

Comment: As you can see in the error as well, the path has to be the path on the filesystem. For example: /usr/home/file.hdfs

Comment: You can directly use `/user/cloudera/input` as your input path

Comment: @PrasadKhode, I had already did that & I get FileNotFound Exception:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /user/cloudera/input does not exist

Comment: @KarateKid I already tried:  /user/cloudera/input and I get FileNotFound exception for that:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /user/cloudera/input does not exist

Comment: can you try with `hdfs:///user/cloudera/input`

Comment: @PrasadKhode tried that and got the execption:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs:/user/cloudera/input, expected: file:///
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:645)

Comment: What does `sc.hadoopConfiguration.get("fs.defaultFS")` return ?

Comment: Where are you running the Spark code? In the VM or outside?

Comment: I am running the code on VM. Spark-Shell.

Answer (score 0):

Add URI while creating file system instance :

```
FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/"), new Configuration())
```

Then simply create path like:

```
 val dirPath=new Path("/user/cloudera/input"‌​)
```

Comment: I gave like this:
FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/"), conf)
Error:
<console>:28: error: not found: type URI
       FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/"), conf)

It couldn't recognize the type: URI
I gave conf since I already have the configuration object.
These are the import statements in my program:
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

Do I need to add any import statement for URI ?

Comment: @Sidhartha `import java.net.URI`

Comment: @philantrovert 
I did as per the suggestion and new error:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File user/cloudera/input does not exist

Order of execution:
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import java.net.URI;
val conf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration;
val fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/"), conf);
val dirPath = new Path("user/cloudera/input");
val filestatus = fs.listStatus(dirPath);
I gave semicolon for sentence separation. Could you let me know what is the mistake I am doing here.

Comment: Could you please try with adding / in the path :  "/user/cloudera/input"

Comment: @aks Tried that and got the below error:
val filestatus = fs.listStatus(dirPath)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /user/cloudera/input does not exist